Conditional statement `if ( ( i != '7' ) && ( j != '8' ) && ( k != '9' ) )` yields erratic results
#include <unistd.h>
void triplet(void);

int main(void)
{
     triplet();
}

void triplet(void)
{
    char i, j, k;
    i = '0';
    j = '1';
    k = '2';
    while (i < j)
    {
        i + 1;
        k = j + 1;
        while (j < k)
        {
            k = j + 1;
            while (k <= '9')
            {
                write(1, &i, 1);
                write(1, &j, 1);
                write(1, &k, 1);
                if ( ( i != '7' ) && ( j != '8' ) && ( k != '9' ) )
                {
                    write(1, ", ", 2);
                }
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

The goal of the if statement is to control when to print the comma-space separator (", ") between the digit combinations. I want to print the separator after every combination except the last one ("789").
The following conditional statement does not work as intended:
if ( ( i != '7' ) && ( j != '8' ) && ( k != '9' ) )

This one does:
if ( !( i == '7' && j == '8' && k == '9' ) )

What is wrong with the first conditional?

What are the values of i, j, and k when write(1, ", ", 2); executes unexpectedly?

Look up "De Morgan's Theorems" — also known as De Morgan's Laws.  Learn them.  You will need them often.  There is nothing "wrong" with either conditional except that they test two completely different conditions.  Since you consider that the second "works", then the first is "wrong" because it is testing a different condition from the second, and De Morgan's Laws would tell you how to rewrite the second using != instead of ==.

Generally these "print a separator except after the last element of a sequence" questions can also be solved by printing the separator first except in front of the first element.

I believe it's a duplicate of De Morgan's rules explained. However I'm reluctant to close this since we have some C-specific answers posted.

Does this answer your question? De Morgan's rules explained

The following could be read as "all three match":
i == '7' && j == '8' && k == '9'

You are negating that.
!( i == '7' && j == '8' && k == '9' )

The negation of "all three match" is "at least one doesn't match".
i != '7' || j != '8' || k != '9'

This is quite different than "none match".
i != '7' && j != '8' && k != '9'


In logic terms, we can derive i != '7' && j != '8' && k != '9' from i == '7' && j == '8' && k == '9' using De Morgan's laws.

!( p && q ) = !p || !q
!( p || q ) = !p && !q

Vlad from Moscow's answer shows the steps.

This if statement
if ( !( i == '7' && j == '8' && k == '9' ) )

is equivalent to
if ( !( i == '7') || !(j == '8' ) || !( k == '9' ) )

that in turn is equivalent to
if ( ( i != '7' ) || ( j != '8' ) ||  ( k != '9' ) )

It is not the same as
if ( ( i != '7' ) && ( j != '8' ) && ( k != '9' ) )

